# K-means Spark variance

Tags: apache-spark, k-means, standard-deviation

I work with k-means algorithm and Spark and I don't understand the relation between sum squared error and variance.

Is there a relation between these values?.

I work with k=1. And the values are

Sum squared error is 10.5679450644

And the standard deviation is:

stdev: [ 2.05035446 2.52269532]

Can I calculate squared error from standard deviation?

Comment: It seems `2.05*2.05+2.52*2.52` is close to 10.56

Answer (score 0):

Variance is defined as

```
1/(n-1) * sum of squares
```

more often than not, people use 1/n instead of 1/(n-1), but that doesn't really change much for large data anyway.

Standard deviation is `sqrt(variance)`, of course.

So yes, there is a *very* simple relation between the three:

```
stddev = sqrt(variance) = sqrt(SSQ / (n-1))
```

Except that in your example, stddev was computed in each axis independently; and maybe your SSQ is actually an *average* SSQ (most likely, SSQ/n then; unfortunately). Or your data set has just 2 points?